# training recruiting app missing context?

Tags: force.com, training

I'm studying for the 401 exam by going through the slide-videos of Salesforce's  "Building Applications with Force.com" parts 1 & 2.

As I try to do the exercises, I'm finding there's a bunch of stuff - objects, profiles, etc., that aren't in my developer org and referred to but not described in the materials - as if they should already be present.  I have this strong feeling there's a course setup that I'm missing.

Have others found this?  Have you found a setup that sets the context for the course?

While I could limp along or just skip the exercise, I'm afraid I'll miss valuable stuff...

Thanks for your help...

Steve

Answer (score 0):

What are the objects and profiles you're missing? If they're custom objects (potentially warehousing) then you're missing a managed package that's required to be installed as part of the course.

Check the package listed here to see if it's the one you need:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/workbook/Content/workshops_install_package.htm